# Prestashop 1.7.X hook not firing when user makes register

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am creating a custom module in Prestashop 1.7.X where I want to get all the details of user when they make register in the store. So for that I am using actionCustomerAccountAdd hook. But this hook is not firing in Prestashop 1.7.X. When I am using the same hook in prestashop 1.6.X its working without any issue.

Here is my sample code

```
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

class Hellouser extends Module
{
    protected $config_form = false;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'hellouser';
        $this->tab = 'other';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'test';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->module_key = '';

        parent::__construct();
        $this->bootstrap = 'true';
        $this->displayName = $this->l('Hello User');
        $this->description = $this->l('This is the demo module');
        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall module?');
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);

        $this->js_path = $this->_path.'views/js/';
        $this->css_path = $this->_path.'views/css/';
        $this->img_path = $this->_path.'views/img/';
        $this->logo_path = $this->_path.'logo.png';
        $this->module_path = $this->_path;
    }

    public function install()
    {
        if (!parent::install() || 
            !$this->registerHook(
                array('actionCustomerAccountAdd')))
            return false;
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        return parent::uninstall();
    }


    public function hookActionCustomerAccountAdd($params) {
        print_r($params);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: check if the hook is registered in modules > positions

Comment: I don't think in prestashop 1.7 there is any option to check module position?

Comment: @tarekfellah's suggestion is valide. if the module is unregistered in a selected hook it wouldn't appear in the list.

Answer (score 0):

try with this 
Edited

```
public function install()
{
    if (!parent::install() || 
        !$this->registerHook('actionCustomerAccountAdd'))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Mode dev is enabled you didn't get any errors? the customer registration is successfully done?

Comment: In appearance > positions you can check if the hook is registered or not

Comment: I am using prestashop 1.7. so is that functionality available with that version?

Comment: in install function add return true; after return false;

Comment: I have seen prestashop position section but there is no such hook like actionCustomerAccountAdd available. But I can see the same hook in Prestashop 1.6.

In fact prestashop 1.7 docs tells that there is hook actionCustomerAccountAdd available but its not showing in the position.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191983/discussion-between-tarek-fellah-and-newuser).